# How to get a state of a play button in Spotify widget?

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I'm working on a new project and a main part of the project is to have it completely web based. I was wondering if and how it would be possible to get the state of the play button, i.e if it's playing or paused. Below is the link. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:4th1RQAelzqgY7wL53UGQt

Comment: Are you saying that you want to scrape that page to determine the state of the play button?

Comment: Get the state of the button how? How do you have reference to that embed?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you want to get the state of the button in an `iframe` (with that embed URL you provided). You can't do that. Due to *same-origin policy* you don't have access to the contents of documents embedded on your site if they're from another domain and there isn't any API provided.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Spotify doesn't provide JS API for the embeds, but they're planning to, as they state on their website:

> Is there a JS SDK for the player? Can I send play/pause commands using Javascript?
>
> The Play button doesn’t have any observable events, nor does it listen for any. Playback can only be triggered by the user clicking the button.
> We’re certainly looking at creating a JS SDK; it’s a bigger project and right now we’re focusing on quickly releasing APIs to open up the general Spotify ecosystem (catalogue, playlists, etc).
> None of these requests are falling on deaf ears, and we’re working hard to bring out as much functionality as we can.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/